# Rails implement an API using Routes pointing to existing controller actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a Rails app that does everything I need it to do via a HTML interface, now I'd like to bolt on an API providing access to bits of the functionality.

How would I do this selective forwarding of some API controller actions to another controller's actions using the Routes.rb?

I have tried the following:

My regular controller routes work fine using:

```
match 'stuff' => 'stuff#index'
get 'stuff/index'
get 'stuff/some_get_action'
post 'stuff/some_post_action'
```

But then when I try for my API:

```
match 'api' => 'api#index'
match 'api/some_get_action' => 'stuff#some_get_action', :via => :get
match 'api/some_post_action' => 'stuff#some_post_action', :via => :post
```

or...

```
match 'api' => 'api#index'
get 'api/some_get_action', :to => 'stuff#some_get_action'
post 'api/some_post_action', :to => 'stuff#some_post_action'
```

I get an error. When I navigate to /api/index to server a HTML page that contains forms for testing the API URLs the url_for raises a 'Routing error' exception saying 'No route matches...'.

Comment: If you want an API on your app, you should stick to the best practices: Introduce versioning such as app/v1 and create different controllers for it. If you stick to the fat model skinny controller approach, this should be pretty easy to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to include ':as => ' and define your route names that you may be using as your link paths.

```
get 'api/some_get_action' => 'stuff#some_get_action', :as => 'some_get_action'
```

and the link path in your index file will have 'some_get_action_path'. Not sure that 'match' or 'get' automatically resolves to a path name, which by setting ':as' it definitely will.

I like your idea for setting up this page for testing. I'm always doing it in the console, which is surely more difficult than simply clicking a link. Your links probably need to infer that they are :json requests, not :http.

Comment: I'm using <% url_for :controller => 'api', :action => 'some_get_action' %>. So I don't think its an issue with the _path helper methods.

Comment: Probably you mean <%= url_for .. %>. Not sure why its not working. If you do change to my 'get...' above, it may also work, and be easier as you only need 'link_to some_get_action_path'.

Comment: Thanks Cole, your suggestion to use the helper method worked (I didn't bother with the :as). It seems like this is a bug in url_for? 

I'd expect it to do the same as the _path helper methods, and I kind of preferred url_for for being more explicit as to which controller/action you are pointing to rather than the magic path methods.